# How can I add a context menu option to a gameobject in the hierarchy to be at the bottom?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(PickupObjects))]
public class PickupObjectsEditor : Editor
{
    [MenuItem("GameObject/Make Pickup Item", false, 10)]
    public static void CreateTextArea()
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject("Test");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        PickupObjects pickupobjects = (PickupObjects)target;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate Pickup Objects"))
        {
            pickupobjects.GeneratePickupObjects();
        }
    }
}
```

This part :

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Make Pickup Item", false, 10)]
public static void CreateTextArea()
{
     GameObject go = new GameObject("Test");
}
```

Will add the "Make Pickup Item" at one place before the end at the bottom :

[image: Priority]

The priority is set to 10 but if I want to add it to the very bottom under the Camera - how do I know what priority it should be?

Comment: If you type a very high number, isn't it going to make it at the very end everytime ?

Comment: The higher the number the more it is moved to the bottom. Simply try various ;) additional info: of the number is about 50 higher then the one before it also adds such a separator line automatically

Comment: Use `Transform.SetSiblingIndex(int index)` if you want to make sure it's right below your camera object.

Answer (score 0):

[Over here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/32bd3a1c008265df4cd53b556446fab60f964834/Editor/Mono/Commands/GOCreationCommands.cs)

You need `priority` > 11

*Line 280:*

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Camera", priority = 11)]
static void CreateCamera(MenuCommand menuCommand)
{
    var parent = menuCommand.context as GameObject;
    Place(ObjectFactory.CreateGameObject("Camera", typeof(Camera), typeof(AudioListener)), parent);
}
```